# How can I best use the compression options of 7z?

Tags: compression, 7-zip, archiving

I have about 900 GB of uncompressed SQL dumps which have a very large amount of common data.  I've been using 7z with the `-mx=9` option because I care much more about the size of the archive than how long it takes to compress.  That makes an archive around 42 GB.

I just discovered the options `mfb`, `md`, and `ms`.  The man page doesn't tell me much about what those options do.  What are fast bytes, dictionary size, and solid archive, and when would I want certain settings, especially in my case?  The [7-Zip documentation](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/method.htm#SevenZipX) says that level 9 compression has a dictionary of 64 MB.  Since my archive is 42 GB, does it help to use a much larger dictionary?  Under what circumstances is it useful to use non-default settings?

Comment: You can only benchmark different settings yourself. Preferably with a smaller dataset of course, but of similar contents.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/616785/how-does-dictionary-size-affect-compression

Comment: When it comes to things like compression, there is no known "best" scenario.  Compression is going to depend *entirely* on the data being compressed and the algorithm being used.

Comment: @Keltari, I get that, which is why I specified the type of data.  I'm using the default algorithm in 7z, if that wasn't clear.  The answer you linked to explains what the dictionary is, but I haven't found good explanations of fast bytes and solid archive.

Comment: @DanielB, yes, I could do a bunch of trial and error, but I was hoping someone could explain those options and why someone would choose particular settings for those options.